# Delete the Folder and Files within A particular Folder in C#

Tags: c#, directory

How can i delete the folder and its files within a particular folder in c#?

When i try to run this code:

```
        try{
            var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"uploads//"+civil_case.Text);
            dir.Attributes = dir.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
            dir.Delete(true);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

It will delete also the uploads folder. I only want to delete one of the folder in the uploads folder.

Ex.

```
     Uploads >
              1stfolder >
                         > content 1.pdf
                         > content 2.png
              2ndfolder >
                         > content 1.pdf
                         > content 2.png
```

I want to delete the `1stfolder` but it turns out it delete the `Uploads` folder too.

Comment: what is it `civil_case.Text`? `1stfolder`

Comment: civil_case.Text is where i capture the the name of the the folder to be deleted. and example for that is the 1stfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
      try {
        string[] myFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"uploads//" +civil_case.Text);
        foreach (string file_path in myFilePaths)
        File.Delete(file_path);
      }
      catch {

      }
```

Comment: it doesn't delete anything there.

Answer (score 0):

i would do it like this :

```
 try
   {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"uploads//"+civil_case.Text);
        dir.Attributes = dir.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;


        //delete    
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(@"uploads//"+civil_case.Text, true);

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: access to the path is denied

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change to :

```
try{

        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"uploads\") ; //change the // to \
         foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dir)
        {
           If(subDir.FullName.Contains(civil_case.Text))
             {
               subDir.Attributes = subDir.Attributes & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
                subDir.Delete(true);

             }
        }
             }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: it also delete the `uploads` folder.

Comment: cannot delete. directory is not empty

Comment: Then the `Delete(true)` will do the job.

Comment: i've added that but it will delete the uploads directory